# Lazy fetching of objects using FindAllBy , for the first time

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When I use criteria queries, the result contains array list of lazy initialized objects. that is, the list has values with handler `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.proxy.GroovyAwareJavassistLazyInitializer`.

This prevent me from doing any array operation (minus, remove etc) in it. When I use, GORM methods, I get array list of actual object types.  How can I get the actual objects in criteria query?

1. The code is listed below.

```
availableTypes = Type.withCriteria() {   
    'in'("roleFrom", from) 
    'in'("roleTo", to) 
}
```

availableTypes (an array list)  has one value , but not actual object but value with a handler of `GroovyAwareJavassistLazyInitializer`

2. availableTypes (an array list) has values with type Type

```
availableTypes = Type.findByRoleFrom(from)
```

---------- Update ----------
I did further troubleshooting, and this is what I found. Probably the above description might be misleading, but I kept it in case it helps.

- When using `findAllBy` for the first time, I get proxy objects rather than the actual instance. Then, I invoke the method through an ajax call, the actual instance is loaded (anything to do with cache loading??). When I refresh the page, it again loads the proxy

```
def typeFrom = Type.findAllByParty(partyFrom)
```

- there is another use of `findAllBy` in the same method, which always returns actual instances.

```
def relFrom = Relation.findAllByParty(partyFrom)
```

- When compared the two classes, the attribute 'party' of class Roles is part of a 1-m relation. like

```
class Role {
      RoleType roleType  
      LocalDate validFrom  
      LocalDate validTo      
      static belongsTo = [party : Party ]  
    ...  
}
```

I know if I do statement like `Party.findAll()`, the role instances would be proxy till they access. But, when using gorm directly on the class (`Role`), why I am getting the proxy objects ???

thanks for the help.

thanks.

Comment: what is the question here? there are a lot of statements regarding what  you are experiencing, but it is difficult to distill it down to a question

Answer (score 1):

Turns out are a couple of possible solutions which I came across but didn't try, such as

- Overloading the equals method so that the proxy and the domain
  object use a primary key instead of the `hashCode` for equality
- Using a join query so that you get actual instances back and not proxies
- `GrailsHibernateUtil.unwrapProxy(o)`
- `HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(object)`

One solution that worked for me was to specify [lazy loading to be false](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/lazy.html) in the domain object mapping.

History of this problem seems to be discussed here: [GRAILS-4614](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4614)

See also: [eager load](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-Javassist-proxies-forcing-eager-load-td2133988.html)

Comment: Eager works for me, but not HibernateProxyHelper.getClassWithoutInitializingProxy(object)